# Customise window border for Chromium Ubuntu

Tags: themes, chromium, window, appearance, menu-bar

I have Chromium browser running on my ubuntu machine, having switched from Chrome because I wanted the native min-max-close buttons in the integrated title bar (Chromium has, Chrome currently doesn't).

I definitely don't want to use the system title bar, as it adds unnecessary height to the top of the window - something the integrated title bar does well. However, when I'm using it, it also changes the window border to be fatter and rounded. This is really annoying because it breaks the uniform look of my window layouts, and overlaps slightly when windows go edge to edge.

All I want is a crisp, clean window border (like with the `system borders and title bar` setting switched on), but with a nice integrated title bar. Any ideas?

I was thinking possibly, this being Chromium and open source and all, that there might be a way to take full control of the window border on the `integrated` setting and lower the thickness (maybe to 0?) to make it look better. But any method that produces the desired results would be welcome.

Yes I know I'm being fussy. This isn't a `crucial`, it's a `nice to have`. But what is life for if not chasing perfection eh? ;) No, I don't want to use Firefox (plugins aren't as good). Cheers!

*Chromium window using integrated title bar and borders = nice title bar, ugly borders*
[image: Chromium window using integrated title bar and borders]

*Chromium window using system title bar and borders = ugly title bar, nice borders*
[image: Chromium window using system title bar and borders]

Comment: This is fixed in Google Chrome Dev and if I'm correct the border will go away starting Google Chrome 94 ([OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/08/chrome-finally-fixes-csd-issues-on-linux)).

Answer (score 2):

Please star and share this bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=920768